# Where to find the schema (.xsd file) for Microsoft docx format

Tags: docx

Consider a user that needs a text of docx document without the headers and footers for processing in R.

If a file.docx is renamed as file.zip and the document document.xml is analyzed - it is a well formed XML document with the text.

Did Microsfot (or other developer) publish a schema for this document.xml subfile in the ZIP package of docx file?

The file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
- <w:body>
- <w:p w:rsidR="00F447D7" w:rsidRPr="00C63308" w:rsidRDefault="00F447D7">
- <w:pPr>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML):

> The format was initially standardised by Ecma (as ECMA-376) and, in
>   later versions, by ISO and IEC (as ISO/IEC 29500).

You can find various versions of the XSD in the [ECMA-376 downloads](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)

document.xml conforms to the WordprocessingML part of the schemas (look for wml.xsd).

Comment: It has some of the XSD schemas for Word Open XML, but it's missing many others (which some of the schemas link to!), like Word12.xsd (I legit downloaded every file there looking for it), and of course it's missing the dublin core files (which some of the xsd schemas also link to, i.e. "dc.xsd", and "dcterms.xsd").

Comment: For that see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/b839fe1f-e1ca-4fa6-8c26-5954d0abbccd

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh643329(v=office.12).aspx

This is version 5.2. On this page you can find a link to version 5.1.

Comment: No, that's a Microsoft extension.

Comment: and it's missing included schemas